# Selenium isn't detecting the chrome prompt to open zoom application as an alert

Tags: python, selenium, exception, webdriver, popup

The pop up in the website is 
[image: This is the alert box that pops up when the website is opened]

The code I used is-

```
    from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='F:/Python/chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://zoom.us/j/6044713838?pwd=ZjdCeEF6a3pRUU5vcU1DS2Rod2VoZz09")

driver.implicitly_wait(15)

alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
alert.accept()
```

The error shown is 
[image: This is the error that's being shown]

I am relatively new to this, could somebody explain why this is happening, and what the possible solution is.

Answer (score 1):

A very weird yet simple reason is that it is not an alert.
It is actually an **OS App Selector**,Selenium cannot interact with it!!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get over it.
You just need to import keyboard package then
import keyboard

> keyboard.send("tab",do_press=True,do_release=True)
> keyboard.send("tab",do_press=True,do_release=True)
> keyboard.send("tab",do_press=True,do_release=True)
> keyboard.send("enter",do_press=True,do_release=True)